# itertools.product(np.arange(0.0, 1.1, 0.1), repeat=30) killed process

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, nested-loops, python-itertools

l have the following function which is composed of 30 nested for loops . When l run my script l get the following error :
**SyntaxError: too many statically nested blocks**

**What the function does ?**

Computes a set of configuration of 31 values (x1,..,x31) with values ranging from 0 to 1 with a step of 0.1 such that the sum of these 31 values equals 1.0.

**What l have tried  ?**

```
def compute_config():

    config = []
    for b1 in np.arange(0.0, 1.1, 0.1):
        for b2 in np.arange(0.0, 1.1, 0.1):
            for b3 in np.arange(0.0, 1.1, 0.1):
                for b4 in np.arange(0.0, 1.1, 0.1):
                    for b5 in np.arange(0.0, 1.1, 0.1):
                        for b6 in np.arange(0.0, 1.1, 0.1):
                            for b7 in np.arange(0.0, 1.1, 0.1):
                                for b8 in np.arange(0.0, 1.1, 0.1):
                                    for b9 in np.arange(0.0, 1.1, 0.1):
                                        for b10 in np.arange(0.0, 1.1, 0.1):
                                            for b11 in np.arange(0.0, 1.1, 0.1):
                                                for b12 in np.arange(0.0, 1.1, 0.1):
                                                    for b13 in np.arange(0.0, 1.1, 0.1):
                                                        for b14 in np.arange(0.0, 1.1, 0.1):
                                                            for b15 in np.arange(0.0, 1.1, 0.1):
                                                                for b16 in np.arange(0.0, 1.1, 0.1):
                                                                    for b17 in np.arange(0.0, 1.1, 0.1):
                                                                        for b18 in np.arange(0.0, 1.1, 0.1):
                                                                            for b19 in np.arange(0.0, 1.1, 0.1):
                                                                                for b20 in np.arange(0.0, 1.1, 0.1):
                                                                                    for b21 in np.arange(0.0, 1.1, 0.1):
                                                                                        for b22 in np.arange(0.0, 1.1,0.1):
                                                                                            for b23 in np.arange(0.0,1.1, 0.1):
                                                                                                for b24 in np.arange(0.0, 1.1, 0.1):
                                                                                                    for b25 in np.arange(0.0, 1.1,  0.1):
                                                                                                        for b26 in np.arange(0.0,1.1,0.1):
                                                                                                            for b27 in np.arange(0.0,1.1,0.1):
                                                                                                                for b28 in np.arange(0.0,1.1,0.1):
                                                                                                                    for b29 in np.arange(0.0,1.1,0.1):
                                                                                                                        for b30 in np.arange(0.0, 1.1,0.1):
                                                                                                                            b31 = 1 - np.sum([b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7,b8, b9, b10, b11, b12,b13,b14,b15,b16, b17, b18, b19, b20, b21, b22,b23, b24, b25, b26, b27,b28,b29,b30])
                                                                                                                            if (b31 >= 0.0):
                                                                                                                                x = [b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7,b8, b9, b10, b11, b12,b13,b14,b15,b16, b17, b18, b19, b20, b21, b22,b23, b24, b25, b26, b27,b28,b29,b30,b31]
                                                                                                                                if (np.sum(x) == 1.0) or (np.sum(x) == 1):
                                                                                                                                    config.append([x])
    config=np.asanyarray(config)
    config=np.squeeze(config)
```

return config

**EDIT :**

Following the answer of  @Martijn Pieters :

```
set_of_configurations=itertools.product(np.arange(0.0, 1.1, 0.1), repeat=30)
```

l would like to a fix a budget by saying l need only 2000 configuration.

Is there any way to do the following :

```
    set_of_configurations=itertools.product(np.arange(0.0, 1.1, 0.1), repeat=30,budget=2000)
   set_of_configurations = np.asarray(list(set_of_configurations))
   set_of_configurations.shape
   (2000,30)
```

Because having 30 loops, we get millions of configurations and the process is killed.

**What l have tried ?**

```
set_of_configurations_1=itertools.product(np.arange(0.0, 1.1, 0.1), repeat=15)
set_of_configurations_2=itertools.product(np.arange(0.0, 1.1, 0.1), repeat=15)
set_of_configurations=itertools.product(set_of_configurations_1,set_of_configurations_2)
```

However l get l **killed process**  at :

```
set_of_configurations=itertools.product(set_of_configurations_1,set_of_configurations_2)
```

Any cue ?

Thank you

Comment: You can use `itertools.product()` to create the Cartesian product instead; `itertools.product(np.arrange(0.0, 1.1, 0.1), repeat=30)`. However, **why would you even want to do this**?

Comment: Thank you a lot @MartijnPieters for the answer. Is it  possible to add a budget ? Let say take only  2000 configurations ?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, lthey represent random coefficients of my data

Comment: @MartijnPieters, please see my update

Answer (score 0):

Relying on the indication given by  @Martjin Pieters, here is the solution. It is all about using isslice :

```
set_of_configurations=itertools.islice(itertools.product(np.arange(0.0, 1.1, 0.1), repeat=30),0,10000)
```

Comment: Given that you're taking only 10000 items, only the last 4 entries in each item can be nonzero - the first 26 will always be zero. Is that what you want? (Also, note that you'll get fewer than 300 configurations with sum 1.0.)

Comment: @MarkDickinson, nice point. So how can l get the configuration from only the 4 last entries ?